# Unit testing Mongo-Hadoop jobs with MrUnit

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, mrunit

How do you unit test mongo-hadoop jobs?

My attempt so far:

```
public class MapperTest {

    MapDriver<Object, BSONObject, Text, IntWritable> d;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        WordMapper mapper = new WordMapper();
        d = MapDriver.newMapDriver(mapper);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMapper() throws IOException {

        BSONObject doc = new BasicBSONObject("sentence", "Two words");
        d.withInput(new Text("anykey"), doc );

        d.withOutput(new Text("Two"), new IntWritable(1));
        d.withOutput(new Text("words"), new IntWritable(1));

        d.runTest();
    }
}
```

Which produces this output:

*No applicable class implementing Serialization in conf at io.serializations for class org.bson.BasicBSONObject*

java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copyWithConf(Serialization.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.copy(TestDriver.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.copyPair(TestDriver.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.MapDriverBase.addInput(MapDriverBase.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.MapDriverBase.withInput(MapDriverBase.java:207)
...

Comment: try converting BSONObject to BSONWritable

Comment: Could you solve your issue? I am facing the same problem at the moment. I guess @Archit comment is not goig to work, since BSONObject is your input, not output

Comment: no, unfortunately not. we decided to ditch hadoop. :)

Comment: out of curiosity, which framework did you switch to?

Comment: @Archit : counter documents in mongodb + amazon redshift together with some love from rabbitmq. so it is a mix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the serializer.
Example :   mapDriver.getConfiguration().setStrings("io.serializations", 
                "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization", MongoSerDe.class.getName());

MongoSerDe src: https://gist.github.com/lfrancke/01d1819a94f14da171e3

But I face error "org.bson.io.BasicOutputBuffer.pipe(Ljava/io/DataOutput;)I" while using this(MongoSerDe).